Getting error while reading csv file with string data
I am writing DeepLearning4j code to read below csv file:
Key,Value
Employee ID,Associate ID
Employee ID,Worker ID
Employee ID,Employee ID

Below is the Java code that i tried with
    DataSet allData1;
    try (RecordReader recordReader1 = new CSVRecordReader(1, ',')) {
        recordReader1.initialize(new FileSplit(new ClassPathResource("EmployeeData.txt").getFile()));

        DataSetIterator iterator = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(recordReader1, 3, 1,1, true);
        allData1 = iterator.next();
    }

However, resulted with below error..
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Employee ID"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:651)
    at org.datavec.api.writable.Text.toDouble(Text.java:590)
    at org.datavec.api.util.ndarray.RecordConverter.toMinibatchArray(RecordConverter.java:207)
    at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.java:153)
    at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:346)
    at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:421)
    at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:53)

Where am I going wrong?
This code is working properly with int and float values in CSV file...
